# Google drive permissions api throws rate limit error after only 20 calls

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a script that is going through a list of folders and transferring ownership using the Drive permissions api. I use that rather than the bean (DriveApp.commands)? because I need to suppress the email notifications.

Although it really should be okay to transfer at least 100 files per minute, I'm getting errors every 3 to 15 files, even though the individual calls take 3 seconds to transfer which is a rate of only 20 per minute, 40 per minute since this probably counts as two separate calls per file.

```
//SNIPPET
  for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {

    var folder = records[i]; // SPECIFIC FOLDER
    if (folder.Transferred === true) {
      //console.log(total+" That folder already transferred -"+folder.gdrive); 
      continue;
    }
    var target = folder.owner;    
    try {
        var result = passOwner(folder.gdrive, target);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        Utilities.sleep(2000);
      }     
  } //for loop

//END OF PROBLEM CODE

function passOwner(fileId, user) {
  if (user == null) return -2;
  try {
    Drive.Permissions.insert({
      'role': 'owner',
      'type': 'user',
      'value': user
    }, fileId, {
      'sendNotificationEmails': 'false'
    });
  } catch (e) {    
    if (e.indexOf("File not found:") > -1) return -1;
    console.log("Taking a nap" + e);
    Utilities.sleep(2000);
    return -1;
  }
  try {
    DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).revokePermissions("ME@ME.com");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return -1;
  } 
  return 0;
}
```

debug log with timestamps

```
Jan 31, 2020, 10:34:17 AM Debug TypeError: Cannot find function indexOf in object GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.permissions.insert failed with error: Rate limit exceeded. User message: "These item(s) could not be shared because a rate limit was exceeded: XXXX".
Jan 31, 2020, 10:34:18 AM Debug 88Folder transferred - 1XGOOGLEDRIVEID
Jan 31, 2020, 10:34:21 AM Debug 89Folder transferred - 1XGOOGLEDRIVEID
Jan 31, 2020, 10:34:24 AM Debug 90Folder transferred - 1XGOOGLEDRIVEID
Jan 31, 2020, 10:34:27 AM Debug 91Folder transferred - 1XGOOGLEDRIVEID
Jan 31, 2020, 10:34:30 AM Debug 92Folder transferred - 1XGOOGLEDRIVEID
Jan 31, 2020, 10:34:33 AM Debug 93Folder transferred - 1XGOOGLEDRIVEID
Jan 31, 2020, 10:34:34 AM Debug TypeError: Cannot find function indexOf in object GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.permissions.insert failed with error: Rate limit exceeded. User message: "These item(s) could not be shared because a rate limit was exceeded: XXXX".
```

Any idea what I should do to troubleshoot further? I have it nap for 2 seconds each time it has a rate limit error, there are no other obvious uses of the api occurring at the same time. Most tellingly, it starts the rate limit crashes almost immediately (it gets fewer than 5 before the first problem).

Comment: The line: `if (e.indexOf("File not found:")` should be: `if (e.message.indexOf("File not found:")`  That may not be the issue, but you are getting an error from that line.

Comment: In the current stage, when the batch requests is used for changing the owner of file, unfortunately, an error occurs like "there is no function to change the owner of this item yet (currently under development).". while the writer and reader permissions can be added without changing the owner with the batch requests. So I think that as the current workaround, how about running the script using the time-driven trigger, until the change of owner can be run with the batch requests? I think that when this can be achieved, your goal can be run by one script run.

Comment: At July 7, 2020, this method got not to be able to be used. But in the current stage, I could confirm that the specification of the method of Permissions: create in Drive API was changed and also, the script in my answer can be used. So you can use the sample script in my answer now. And also, I created [a Google Apps Script library](https://github.com/tanaikech/OwnershipTransfer) for transferring the ownership of the specific folder including the files and folders with keeping the folder structure. So also, I added it. If these leads to the solution of your issue, I'm glad.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I could confirm that the owner of files got to be able to be changed by the batch requests with Drive API. So I would like to propose a sample script for achieving your goal as follows.

When the batch requests is used, 100 API requests can be run by one API call. And also, each task can run with the asynchronous process. By this, both the process cost and quota cost can be reduced.

#### Sample script:

When you use this script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services). When `records` of your script is used, the script becomes as follows.

```
function myFunction() {
  // Please set the values of "records".
  const records = [
    {Transferred: false, owner: "###@gmail.com", gdrive: "### fileId 1###"},
    {Transferred: true, owner: "###@gmail.com", gdrive: "### fileId 2###"},
    {Transferred: false, owner: "###@gmail.com", gdrive: "### fileId 3###"},
    ,
    ,
    ,
  ];
  
  // Create requests for the batch request.
  const requests = records.reduce((ar, {Transferred, owner, gdrive}) => {
    if (Transferred === false) {
      ar.push({
        method: "POST",
        endpoint: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${gdrive}/permissions?transferOwnership=true`,
        requestBody: {
          role: "owner",
          type: "user",
          emailAddress: owner
        }
      });
    };
    return ar;
  }, []);

  // Run batch requests.
  const limit = 100;
  const split = Math.ceil(requests.length / limit);
  const boundary = "xxxxxxxxxx";
  for (let i = 0; i < split; i++) {
    const object = {batchPath: "batch/drive/v3", requests: requests.splice(0, limit)};
    const payload = object.requests.reduce((s, e, i) => s += "Content-Type: application/http\r\nContent-ID: " + i + "\r\n\r\n" + e.method + " " + e.endpoint + "\r\nContent-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n" + JSON.stringify(e.requestBody) + "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n", "--" + boundary + "\r\n");
    const params = {method: "post", contentType: "multipart/mixed; boundary=" + boundary, payload: payload, headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}, muteHttpExceptions: true};
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/" + object.batchPath, params);
    console.log(res.getContentText())
  }
  
  // DriveApp.createFile()  // This is used for automatically detected the scope of https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive. This scope is required to use the method of Permissions: create in Drive API.
}
```

#### Note:

- In above script, even when the length of `records` is more than 100, the script works.
- When `sendNotificationEmail=false` is used, an error of `The sendNotificationEmail parameter is only applicable for permissions of type 'user' or 'group', and must not be disabled for ownership transfers.` occurs. So in this script, `sendNotificationEmail=false` is not used.

#### References:

- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)

### Updated: July 13, 2020

I confirmed that at July 7, 2020, this method got not to be able to be used. But, at July 10, 2020, I confirmed that the specification of the method of Permissions: create in Drive API was changed, and this sample script got to be able to be used again. It's that `enforceSingleParent` and `moveToNewOwnersRoot` got to be able to be correctly used. By modified `enforceSingleParent` and `moveToNewOwnersRoot`, the ownership of the specific folder including the files and sub-folders got to be able to be also transferred with kept the folder structure. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/OwnershipTransfer) But in the current stage, I'm not sure whether this is the permanent specification.